# How to decode Hash password to string in SHA 256

Tags: php, hash, sha256

```
$password=PREFIXE.hash("sha256",$_POST['Password']).SUFFIXE;
```

How to decode Hash password to string in SHA 256

Comment: you can't decode a hash. hashing has a different purpose from encryption

Answer (score 1):

As Frederico says you cant really encrypt but maybe a database could be of use in individual cases, google "sha256 database".

Note: using these kind of websites can pose a security risk e.g. if you enter a secure passwords in plain text into the encoding form they will save it and the corresponding hash to grow their database.